# Где достать базу названий процессов игр?

Tags: поиск-данных

Discord может определить, в какую игру сейчас играет юзер.

Логично предположить, что он проверяет активные процессы и сравнивает их со своей базой.

А где-нибудь возможно достать подобную базу названий процессов игр?

Comment: Я не видел, как это работает, но вы уверены, что он проверяет процессы? Умеет ли он определять игры без стима?

Comment: Я не уверен, но в первых версиях они смотрели процессы и из какой папки были запущены, потом название папки сравнивают со своей базой. Я пришёл к такому вывод, потому что переименовав папку с игрой, он не видел игру. Насколько мне известно сейчас другой алгоритм. Посмотрите в сторону их API, может там что есть.